# gridview cancel row selection when row has controls

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview, asp.net-2.0

I have a gridview in ASP.net 2.0 that has a small peace of javascript code that when you click the row, it will be selected.

```
cell.Attributes.Add("onClick", Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this, "Select$" + row.RowIndex.ToString()));
```

This code works perfect, but when I have a link or button in a gridview row and as soon as that will be clicked, a postback will occur and override the link or button action.

**My question, knows anybody a solution to cancel the row javascript onclick event?**

The following solutions I have unsuccessfully tested:

- `return false;`
- jQuery with `event.stopImmediatePropagation` works, but I use pagination so the event doesn't bound to the new page.
- jQuery with `.live("click", function(){...});` works with pagination, but the `event.stopImmediatePropagation` isn't supported in `live` and `delegate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the following solution:

Place this in the control in the gridview:

```
... onClientClick="return ShowSomething(this);" ...
```

And this in the page/head:

```
function ShowSomething(elm) {
    var e = new jQuery.Event(window.event);
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();  // Stop now!!!

    var that = jQuery(elm);

    return false;
}
```